# Where is the Ubuntu install taking place?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 along side my Windows 10 and I keep running out of memory during the install. It appears that wherever this install is taking place only has 7.9GB available and it needs more. This is without getting to choose where this is 7.9GB is, and I have no idea how to increase the size. Where is this 7.9GB, and how do I either make that bigger or switch to somewhere else that is?

This happens right after the step where it asks if I want to download updates while installing ubuntu and or install third-party software for graphics etc. I'm allowed to open up a window to see why there are 0 bytes remaining and "clear space" but that window doesn't have admin rights so you can't really clear anything and I think pretty much everything is essential anyway.

From that window I can pull up a context menu and click open folder. From open folder I can right click and open terminal (but ctrl+alt+t never works). From the terminal i've tried removing files using "sudo rm -rf whatever" which works, but I don't know what I can remove and the install eventually fails anyway. I can pull up the partitioner using "sudo gparted" and play around. I createad a partition for ubuntu but now I'm having trouble getting to the point where it even matters.

Can I choose to make this install happen on a partition I create with gparted instead of the 7.9GB mystery space?

Comment: Use gparted to create partitions you want or need, then use Something Else to choose(change button) those partitions. Minimum is / (root) & swap. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu and: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: Ditto the above by oldfred, but /swap may not be important if you have 8GB or more of RAM (unless you often use greater than the volume of RAM your system has installed). And/or if you are using an SSD and have /tmp running from RAM and a smaller RAM quantity (ie: tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0 in your /etc/fstab file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dual boot your machine..ubuntu needs some unallocated memory.
For that open disk management select any big disk and right click select option>shrink volume...type 70000mb(thats enough to run smoothly) and hit enter..u will get a black area as unallocated..now make bootable pendrive of Ubuntu shut down ur system boot ur pendrive using boot key and select usb select install ubuntu, going further u will get an option >install ubuntu alongside windows click it and go ahead..this should install ubuntu on your system (make sure both of them are in UEFI mode or one which your machine is running on(check in BIOS menu)) if it doesn't appear then choose "something else"option and you will have to manually partition unallocated (sample images attached here)
[image]
[image: i will prefer install alongside if u wish to do it manually do these]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Continue installation...reboot after completion.. hope this helps :)

Comment: This will allot proper memory..and u wont be having 7.9gb problem..coz u haven't setup ubuntu properly...

Answer (score 1):

There is an [open bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521173) on this issue.  Apparently there is a bug in the kernel code used in ubuntu 16.04 which fails to clear errors generated by pci subsystem.  So as soon as one starts it up it just keeps looping and writing.

I can't install on my asus m32cd either.

However, you can install ubuntu 12.04 lts 32-bit and then upgrade to 14.04 in the interim.

Answer (score 0):

Although the partition did not show up in gparted, I did see a 7.9GB partition when I booted to windows and ran Disk Management.

The install shouldn't be hitting a wall at 7.9GB because it shouldn't need all that space. There was another issue happening during the install that seems to have looped continuously, filling the log with the same error messages. Because the log fills up the symptom is not enough disk space, but the real issue is that there is an error elsewhere. If you notice an error message saying you've run out of room check the log to see if it is the reason.

I'm still not finished setting up Ubuntu, but I found someone [post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521173) the solution as being to modify /etc/default/grub and and add pci=noaer like this
"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"
then the problem goes away. I just need to figure out how to do this but I think it will work.