# After triple boot, bootloader ubuntu not showing up

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I had Kali linux and ubuntu. And i had two partition, for both of them. I parted ubuntu part, succesfully using gparted. Afterwards, i installed win 7 to the partition that is empty. After installation, i can't see my ubuntu files and stuff using, Disk Usage Analyser, but can't see ubuntu in bootloader. I also tried `boot-repair`, and, this

```
root@hackleyecemseni:~# update-grub

Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.0.0-kali1-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.0.0-kali1-amd64
  No volume groups found
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
done
```

Also, i wasn't able to see kali linux, before doing `boot-repair`, yet it did not fix ubuntu.

Comment: When u installed windows after linux windows bootloader installed and replaced grub..check in BIOS menu if there is still Ubuntu boot loader...if yes set it highest priority

Comment: i just realized, my ubuntu partition is now unallocated :( does this mean in the process of installing windows my ubuntu deleted?

Comment: Yes...perhaps u went the wrong way..u need to install windows first and then ubuntu in unallocated space that will make perfect dual boot for more references read my ans http://askubuntu.com/a/827264/593116

Comment: unallocated means empty area? man i fell so bad right now. i had so much thing in that partition

Comment: Ya i understand..when i did for first time... same happened with me...still u can try recovering data if possible...my favourite tool is : https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/how-can-i-recover-my-data-from-an-unallocated-hard-disk.html

Comment: U will probably need hard-disk external with logical memory..m not sure but do it 